# what's the difference between Cohen-Daubechies-Fauraue 9/7 transformation and Discrete cosine transform?

Tags: transformation, wavelets

can someone explain, what's the difference between this 2 tranformations?
[DCT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform) and [CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen-Daubechies-Feauveau_wavelet)

Greetings

Comment: Different acronyms...

Comment: realy?  i think that the result looks different

Comment: One decomposes a signal into a sum of CDF wavelets, the other decomposes a signal into a sum of cosines. One obvious difference is that the basis functions of the former are compactly supported (they are zero outside a finite interval) while those of the latter span the entire signal. Beyond that, it sounds like you're asking "Explain DCT to me, then explain CDF", which is too broad for this sort of site.